# Merge multiple HTML line breaks into one with PHP? Line-Breaks caused by P and BR tags

Tags: php, html, string, filter

**First part of question: p tag**

I have a string that contains text with unnecessary line breaks caused by p tags, example:

```
<p>hi everyone,</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Here comes the content I wanted to write...</p>
```

I would like to filter these empty p tags and merge them into one:

```
<p>hi everyone,</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Here comes the content I wanted to write...</p>
```

How can this be done?

Thank you!

---

**Second part of question: br tag**

Sometimes the string contains br tags that are causing line breaks as well, example:

```
that is all I wanted to write.<br />
<br />
&nbsp;<br />
<br />
&nbsp;<br />
<br />
bye
```

This should become:

```
that is all I wanted to write.<br />
<br />
bye
```

Comment: It's just a PHP string containing HTML. There is no other code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using str_replace

```
$content = str_replace(array("<p>&nbsp;</p>\n", "&nbsp;<br />\n"), array('', ''), $content);
```

To use regex:

```
$content = preg_replace('/((<p\s*\/?>\s*)&nbsp;(<\/p\s*\/?>\s*))+/im', "<p>&nbsp;</p>\n", $content);
```

and for BRs

```
$content = preg_replace('/(&nbsp;(<br\s*\/?>\s*)|(<br\s*\/?>\s*))+/im', "<br />\n", $content);
```

**EDIT**
Heres *why* your regex works (hopefully so you can understand it a bit :) ):

```
/((\\n\s*))+/im
^  ^^^ ^^  ^^^^
|  \|/ ||  ||\|
|   |  ||  || -- Flags
|   |  ||  |-- Regex End Character
|   |  ||  -- One or more of the preceeding character(s)
|   |  |-- Zero or More of the preceeding character(s)
|   |  -- String Character
|   -- Newline Character (Escaped)
-- Regex Start Character
```

Every regex expression must start and end with the same character. In this case, i've used the forward slash character.

The ( character indicates an expression block (to replace)
The Newline character is `\n`. Because the backslash is used as the escape character in regex, you will need to escape it: `\\n`.

The string character is `\s`. This will search for a string. The `*` character means to search for 0 or more of the preceeding expression, in this case, `search for zero or more strings: \s*`.

The + symbols searches for ONE or more of the preceeding expresssion. In this case, the preceeding expression is `(\\n\s*)`, so as long as that expression is found once or more, the preg_replace function will find something.

The flags I've used `i` and `m` means case **I**nsensitive, (not really needed for a newline expression), and **M**ultiline - meaning the expression can go over multiple lines of code, instead of the code needing to be on one line.

Comment: This is the only solution :)

Comment: You could do it with preg_replace(), but it'd be over complicated for the specific examples needs! :)

Comment: It may be simple but it is not exactly what the questioner actually wanted.

Comment: @PhilCross Thanks for your quick answer. Using this on the example above gives me: 

`<p>hi everyone,</p>
<p>Here comes the content I wanted to write...</p>`

The first `<p>&nbsp;</p>` is removed as well.

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV I have updated my answer, to contain the regex for replacing multiple instances of the tag with a single one. I have tested the <p> tags, however the <br /> one is slightly more complicated to write a regex for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. p tag merging works great. Regex for br looks indeed quite complicated. As the br tag is merged into a single one `<br />`, I just changed `"<br />\n"` to `"<br />\n<br />"` to achieve the desired output from the example... Respect, nice answer ;)

Comment: @PhilCross By the way; I got a scenario where `<br />` is actually `\n`. I modified your BR-version to: `preg_replace("/( (\\n\s*))+/im", "\n", $content)` which seems to work, even if I do not understand the syntax 100%.

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV I have updated my answer with your newline code, and an explanation as to why it works. For your information, I always use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test my expressions, its quite useful!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your big help! And thanks for pointing out the regex tool. Note: I used a space after the first bracket `"/( (\\n\s*))+/im"`