# remove empty lines and convert into single space php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a data in mysql table:

```
<p>aaaa</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>asd</p>
```

and I need to display it like this:

```
aaaa asd
```

But I can't seem to get it right.

First I'm using this code:

```
$string = htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($string)); // $string contains data from the table
```

and I tried this: ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3760816/1235167))

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string));
```

and also this: ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3760828/1235167))

```
$string = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $string);
```

but nothing works!
when I use `echo $string;` it still shows an empty line. can anyone give a solution?

Comment: @Ravenix what do you mean? I thought \s+ means "one or more new line"?

Comment: Did you try to add p {display: inline-block;} to your css?

Comment: Do you want to keep the `<p>` tags? Those are causing the line breaks.

Comment: @DevNiels yes, I just tried it after you suggested it, but still the same result..

Comment: @simon no, I don't want any empty lines. all empty lines was supposed to be replaced with a single space

Comment: From your example, It sounds like you just want to rip off all of the <p> </p> Tags in your "string" and then maybe wrap the whole lot up in paragraph tags once that is done...

Comment: I think this answer can solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/16809389/3615630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779464/php-simple-way-to-replace-or-remove-empty-lines-with-str-replace).
Or try:
`$line_out = preg_replace('/[\n\r]+/', '', $line_in);`

Comment: this one works. thanks! I've searched google for almost an hour but I don't remember seeing that answer.. weird...

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$x = '<p>aaaa</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>asd</p>';
$spaces = array('&nbsp;',' ');
echo str_replace($spaces,'',strip_tags($x));
```

Comment: this was supposed to worked perfectly, but it returns multiple spaces. even though the second parameter is an empty string. why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The line breaks are caused by the `<p>` tags because they are [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements):

> Browsers typically display the block-level element with a newline both before and after the element.

If you don't want HTML tags in your string you can remove them with 
[strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
$string = strip_tags($string);
```

If you want to keep the `<p>` tags, you need to display them as inline elements using CSS:

```
p {
    display: inline; /* or display: inline-block; */
}
```

Comment: does that mean I don't need to use htmlspecialchars_decode or something to display the data from database? I thought strip_tags() is not secure enough?

Comment: @dapidmini depends on where the data is coming from. If this data is user input you need to use `htmlspecialchars()` on it